# Update global variable inside a function inside a method

Tags: python, scope

I have a function inside a method of a class like this:

```
class A():               
    def run(self):

        exit=False

        def walk():
             global exit
             #DoStuff - change exit variable
        walk()
        print(exit)
```

Now, the function `walk` should change the `exit` variable. But this variable is outside of the function always `False` like set before. How can I change this variable using as a flag to access this outside the function if this function set this varibale to `True`? I am rather confused about the scope of this variable. I use python 3.6.

Comment: Do you really want a *global* variable? The `exit` inside `run` is local, not global.

Comment: The exit inside of run is not a global exit. so when you call `walk()` and `print(exit)` you are printing the local exit.

Comment: Why do you have a nested function in the first place? the function walk sounds completely independent to what run would do

Comment: I need just a flag varibale inside the run method which should be changed inside the walk function. How can I manag this properly?

Comment: Try `nonlocal exit` in place of `global exit`.

Comment: So how can I make it then global. Or if this is wrong, how can I make this variabale exit changing within walk accessable outside of walk? This blows up my mind!

Comment: Don't global things if possible. They get messy as your code grows in size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current setup

```
class A:
    def run(self):
        exit = False

        def walk():
             global exit
             exit = True
        walk()
        print(exit)

a = A()
a.run() # False
print(exit) # True
```

prints `False` because the `exit` you print inside `run` lives in the scope of `run`, it is not a global variable. You are actually setting a global variable `exit` in `walk` - see the second call to `print` giving `True`.

What you want instead of `global` is the `nonlocal` keyword which lets you modify free variables. Let's examine what happens without `global` first, however.

```
class A:
    def run(self):
        exit = False

        def walk():
             exit = True
        walk()
        print(exit)

a = A()
a.run() # False
```

The code prints `False` because `run` does not care about the creation of local variables that are assigned in `walk`. With the addition of `nonlocal` however

```
class A:
    def run(self):
        exit = False

        def walk():
             nonlocal exit
             exit = True
        walk()
        print(exit)

a = A()
a.run() # True
```

the code will output `True`, because `exit = True` is now setting the variable `exit` in the *enclosing, nonlocal* scope of `run`.

The key topics you should research for additional context are closures and free variables.

Comment: Thanks! But For my use case I don't need the exit varibale to be global in this case. I just need it in the scope of run changed of function walk.

Comment: @tado Yes, I just wanted to explain what's going on by presenting different scenarios. You need the code with `nonlocal`.

Comment: One question to the sope with unlocal. Is this variabale now only bounded to this class? Because I use other classes with same varibale.

Comment: @tado that question is a little ambiguous, depending on what you mean by "bounded to class". Maybe read up a little on Python scoping rules. If the question is not clear by then, you might have the tools to formulate it better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `nonlocal` keyword here. Check it out:

```
>>> def run():
...   e=False
...   print(e)
...   def walk():
...     nonlocal e
...     e=True
...     print(e)
...   walk()
...   print(e)
...
>>> run()
False
True
True
```

However, this is pretty bad form! It would be standard to have the variable `exit` be a property of the class A.

```
class A():

    def __init__(self):
        self.exit = False

    def run(self):
        self.exit = False

        def walk():
            #DoStuff with self.exit variable
            self.exit = True
        walk()
        print(self.exit)
```

As an aside, `exit` is a reserved keyword in Python, so you should avoid giving your variables that name if you don't want to break the language.

Comment: thanks. Do I need a init method for a class varibale? Or is there another way?

Comment: `init()` is the function that is called when you create an instance of a class. So any instance-specific stuff that you want to set up happens within that function. In practice, you would so something like `a = A()` somewhere in your script and then you'd have access to the property `a.exit`

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-__init__-method-in-python-class/